# Refactoring a query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a simplified code like below:

```
PROCEDURE MY_PROC (d1 IN DATE) IS
CURSOR curs IS SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE date1 = d1;
result BOOLEAN;
rTab1 TABLE1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN curs;
    FETCH curs INTO rTab1 ;
    result := curs%FOUND;
CLOSE curs;
IF result = FALSE THEN
    rTab1.NUM_ID := 0;
END IF;
SELECT * FROM TAB2 WHERE NVL(NUM_ID, 0) = rTab1.NUM_ID;
END;
```

Is it possible to write everything in one query? I mean without having to chceck if  rTab1.NUM_ID exists. Maybe with join? And get same results at the end like above?
I mean something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1, TAB2 
WHERE NVL(TAB1.NUM_ID, 0) = TAB2.NUM_ID
AND date1 = d1;
```

Comment: On a side note: Never use commas to join tables. This was how it was done in the 1980s, but then, in 1992, explicit joins ( `[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, etc.) were officially invented to overcome the shortcomings of the comma syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is looking for tab1 rows where the date matches the given date d1.

- If there is one matching row, then its num_id is used.
- If there is more than one matching row, then one of their num_ids is used arbitrarily.
- If there is no matching row, the value 0 is used.

Then with that value the code selects all matching tab2 rows.

This can be done with a single query. To get only one tab1.num_id, use `MIN`, `MAX` or `ANY_VALUE`. To get a zero when there is no date match use `NVL` or `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM tab2
WHERE NVL(num_id, 0) = (SELECT NVL(MIN(num_id), 0) FROM tab1 WHERE date1 = d1);
```

Comment: But it seems, that neither nvl nor coalesce works when there is no matching row. It seems only to works, when there is a matching row and when the value is NULL...

Comment: @Boneist: You are mistaken. `SELECT MIN(...)` without a `GROUP BY` always results in one row. If there is no row in the table matching the `WHERE` clause, the result is null, which I convert into zero with `NVL`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner duh, that'll teach me for posting too early!